# Plot .geojson coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geojson, geopandas, wkt

For those wanting to test the contents of their `.geojson` files, by visualising/ plotting `coordinates`.

I didn't see a go-to solution online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main(root: Path):
    root = str(root)
    filenames = os.listdir(root)
    geojson_filenames = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.geojson'), filenames))
    for gjf in geojson_filenames:
        df = gpd.read_file(f'{root}/{gjf}')
        df.plot(aspect=1)
        plt.get_current_fig_manager().canvas.set_window_title(gjf)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ROOT = Path('some/path/)
    main(ROOT)
```

Feel free to critique or suggest improvements.